# Is it possible to harvest videos of a topic from YouTube and how?

Tags: video, youtube-api, freebase

I want to do some video classification experiments and I need a dataset about pet videos. Can I harvest videos on YouTube?
I know Youtube has this awesome api: Freebase Topics. But from the [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic) it provides, I can only get the name of the videos about dogs like this:

```
Funny babies annoying dogs - Cute dog & baby compilation (M1djO19aSFQ)
```

I don't even know what the string means in the brackets.

how can I download these videos or is there any other datasets about pet videos?
Thanks!

Comment: you would have to find the tags and group by that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the print statement in the example program, you can see what's included:

```
  print "%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
    search_result["id"]["videoId"])
```

so the string the parentheses is the video ID (which you can also confirm empirically by searching for it and seeing that the video is the first hit that comes up).  If you want different metadata output, simply modify the example program.

It's generally against the YouTube Terms of Service to download videos.